# Can't figure out why I keep getting this error in regards to opening the gbd path while using the InsertCursor

Tags: arcpy

```
    listOfPoints = [(6002672.58675, 2092447.04362), (6003672.58675, 
  2093447.04362), (6004672.58675, 2093447.04362), (6004672.58675,   
  2091447.04362)] 
polyName = 'New Polygon' 
polyID = 54321 
blockPoly = r'C:\Users\your.name\some_folder\SanFrancisco.gdb\Chapter3Results\TestPolygo
insertCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(blockPoly, 
  ['SHAPE@','BLOCK','BLOCKID']) 
polyArray = arcpy.Array() 
for pointsPair in listOfPoints: 
    newPoint = arcpy.Point(*pointsPair) 
    polyArray.add(newPoint) 
newPoly = arcpy.Polygon(polyArray) 
insertData = newPoly, polyName, polyID 
insertCursor.insertRow(insertData) 
del insertCursor
```

for blockPoly, I used the whole file path and keep running into this error.

```
RuntimeError: cannot open 'C:SanFrancisco.gdb/Chapter3Results/TestPolygon'
```

Comment: Try setting `blockPoly` to be a full rather than partial path to that feature class.

Comment: Also consider using with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(blockPoly, ['SHAPE@','BLOCK','BLOCKID'])  as insertCursor : to clean up the locks when it's done - perhaps the path is right but you still have a latent lock from a previous iteration, if this is the case then you need to close whatever is locking it to release the locks, in the gdb there will be .lock files that contain the process ID which can be terminated with 'end task' - I know it's a bit heavy handed but if your code has previously fallen over before del insertCursor that lock still exists and the only way to release is to close the thread.

Comment: As @PolyGeo implied, that `blockPoly` path is not a whole file path in the code you posted.  A full path would start with something like `r'C:\'` or `r'\\servername\sharename'` (or similar).  Eg, `r'C:\Users\your.name\some_folder\SanFrancisco.gdb\Chapter3Results\TestPolygon'`

Comment: You should also avoid ever using the `Polygon` constructor without a spatial_reference parameter (extracted from an `arcpy.Describe` on the target feature class). In this particular case, you won't corrupt the geometry, but in the real world it's likely (and somewhat baffling, since the error occurs there, but isn't manifested until later)

Comment: @SonofaBeach@PolyGeo
I did use the full path, but I remove some bits as it contains my real name. :(

Comment: You need to make this explicit by editing your code, including the full path, and replace any instances of confidential data (eg, yourname) with some equivalent obfuscated version, such as "user.name".

Comment: @MichaelStimson I'm learning to use Arcpy from ArcPy and ArcGIS - Second Edition By Silas Toms and Dara O'Beirne. 
Could you tell me more?

Comment: What is the *real* path to the geodatabase? We cannot tell from your code whether it exists or not, navigate to it in ArcCatalog and copy/paste the path from the browser bar; your error message does not match your code, please update. Does it contain invalid characters? On a brief search I can see that the code by Esri does not contain code using a with block with insert cursor however I can assure you that I have a few working examples of a with block and arcpy.da.InsertCursor.

Comment: The *unable to open* error message will occur for 4 situations: 1 the path isn't correct, in which case copy/paste the full path. 2 the path is correct but there's still a lock from a failed process or you have the database open in ArcCatalog or ArcMap - try restarting Windows and this one should go away. 3 the database is corrupt - you can eliminate the 3rd by previewing the feature class in catalog if it appears fine then this probably isn't the problem but to be safe create a new GDB and copy/paste the feature class. 4 The geodatabase exists but is a newer version than your Esri install.